# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpleaudio'

Tags: python, simpleaudioengine

Basically, I recently started Python. I'm working on a project where I need audio to play. I searched up some libraries that can play audio and tried simpleaudio. I'm using Windows and sucessfull installed simpleaudio using: `pip3 install simpleaudio`.

However, when I tried to use simpleaudio in my project with `import simpleaudio as sa`, it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\coding\python\python projects\random tests\soundtest.py", line 1, in 
    import simpleaudio as sa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpleaudio'

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are executing your script with python 3.x and not python 2.x? With `pip3`, you installed your package for python 3 and therefore it will not be available in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

After I installed simpleaudio, `import simpleaudio as sa` worked with no errors.  I've run into similar errors before, and it was always because the version of pip I was using and the Python interpreter I was using didn't match.  You probably need to either switch to using the same interpreter as pip3 or install the package for whatever interpreter you're using

Answer (score 0):

The most probable issue is the use of differing version of python. For instance if you use pip3 it is for python3 only

Since the module was not found try

```
pip install simpleaudio
```

and then importing again

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you installed the library for python2 instead of python3. In ubuntu pip is python2 and pip3 is python3- I'm not sure if that's the case on windows or not.